# Brief­wech­sel auch für E-Mail?

Tags: word-usage

Kann man das Wort *Briefwechsel* im Bezug auf E-Mail-Korrespondenz nutzen oder klingt das etwas crazy?

> Kannst du mir den ganzen Briefwechsel schicken?

Comment: Ja, kann man. Wird jeder sofort verstehen, auch wenn sich die Antworter hier aus unerfindlichen Gründen spreizen.

Comment: Klar, _kann_ man machen... man muss sich aber auch nicht mit der erstbesten Lösung zufrieden geben, wenn's besser geht. Und Google findet z.B. für "Briefwechsel" gerade mal 320T Einträge - für "Korrespondenz" 4.3M... ich denke mal, das häufigere Wort ist auch gängiger (zumindest in diesem Fall).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Metaphern *Brief* und *Post* haben sich im Deutschen für E-Mail nie durchgesetzt, stattdessen kann man aber heutzutage meist das *E* weglassen. Damit ergeben sich folgende Möglichkeiten, die teilweise in anderen Antworten bereits genannt wurden:

- *Mailwechsel*
- *Mailverlauf* oder teilanglisiert *Mailhistorie*
- *Mailkorrespondenz*
- *Mailverkehr* – eher für die Infrastruktur als für ein „Gespräch“
- *Mailkonversation*
- *alle (relevanten) Mails*
- *sämtliche (relevante) Mails*

Wie @Thomas schon andeutet, lässt sich auch allgemeiner von *Schriftverkehr* etc. sprechen. Darunter können ggf. auch Briefe, Kurznachrichten, Chats und Faxe fallen. Alternativ kann man auch ohne diese Komposita auskommen, wenn das Medium aus dem Kontext klar wird, also *Korrespondenz* usw.

Schlussendlich gibt es zumindest im Netzjargon noch einen Anglizismus, der v.a. für Mailinglisten, Newsgroups und Foren verwendet wird und verschiedene eher saloppe Eindeutschungen hat:

- *Thread* → *Strang, Faden, „Fred“* …

Answer (score 5):

Wenn es sich um einen nicht besonders förmlichen Kontext handelt würde ich "E-Mail-Verkehr" benutzen. Im förmlichen Kontext scheint mir "E-Mail-Korrespondenz" bereits das richtige Wort zu sein.

Answer (score 3):

Ich würde da eher “Korrespondenz“ verwenden. “Schriftwechsel“ wäre auch noch denkbar.